# .NET and Geocortex Workflow Parse AD user as current user to email

Tags: .net, active-directory, workflow, gis

Newbie Geocortex admin here still learning the ropes. Trying to parse the current user logged into Geocortex (using the GetCurrentUser Activity) to create an email workflow. I've got all the steps sorted except how the GetCurrentUser activity presents the user credentials.

What I need is a return of "jsmith@company.com".

The GetCurrentUser activity returns "John Smith (jsmith@DOMAIN_NAME)@company.com)

Just trying to figure out the language to construct it within Geocortex so it splits out between the **"John Smith ("** and **"@DOMAIN_NAME)"** so I am left with just jsmith@company.com

Cheers!

Comment: Are you looking for the language recommendation on **SO** ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, had a colleague provide the answer:

```
currentuser.Substring(currentuser.IndexOf("(") + 1, currentuser.IndexOf("@", currentuser.IndexOf("(")) - currentuser.IndexOf("(") - 1) + "@company.com"
```